# Adding a sorting algorithm (bubble sort) to a program

Tags: c++, function, bubble-sort

Here is a question i got from a past paper in our university:

1. The user can input the array size
2. User can enter some values to the array;(until it fit the array size given by the user
3. The array input by user .should be sorted using bubble sort algorithm

For example

- I input the size 3
- I can enter three numbers let's assume `12, 2, 5`

It should be sorted like this 2.5.12

Using two functions, an input function and the bubble sort algorithm function, I wrote the input function like this:

```
void input_score(int array[], int score)
{
    for(int i=0; i<score; i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter the machine values\n";
        cin>>array[i];
    }
  for(int i=0; i<score; i++)
    {
        cout<<array[i];
    }
}
```

Then after that I want to call the bubble sort algorithm function to sort it and print:

```
void sort_array(int array[],int score){
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<score;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<score;j++){
            if(array[i]>array[j]){
                temp=array[i];
                array[i]=array[j];
                array[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Sorted elements\n";

    for(i=0;i<score;i++)
        cout<<array[i]<<"\n;
}
```

So i wrote the statement in the input function like this

```
for(i=0;i<=size;i++){
   sort_array(array[i],size);
}
```

Am i correct?
By the way here is my main function

```
int main()
{
    cout<<" enter number of machines\n";
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    int array[a];
    input_score(array,a);
}
```

Comment: Does your program work? Is there a problem with it?

Comment: it comiples but it wont calling the bubble sort algorithm

Comment: This program is short enough that you should be able to step through it with a debugger.  That will show you (in only a couple of minutes) where your problem lies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i call this function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692022/how-can-i-call-this-function)

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5gBIizwsY0

Answer (score 2):

No you should not call

`for(i=0;i<=size;i++){ 
sort_array(array[i],size)
}`

you should just call

`sort_array(array,a);`

becuase your `void sort_array(int array[],int score){` takes first parameter as array and not int.. 
try below main and it should work.

```
int main()
{
    cout<<" enter number of machines\n";
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    int array[1000];
    input_score(array,a);
    sort_array(array,a);
}
```

or if you want to call sort in input...

```
void input_score(int array[], int score)
{
    for(int i=0; i<score; i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter the machine values\n";
        cin>>array[i];
    }
  for(int i=0; i<score; i++)
    {
        cout<<array[i];

    }
    sort_array(array,score);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell from where are you calling the sorting function but you should call it from function input_score. And also using for loop for calling the sort function is unnecessary.
Just call function once, like :

```
sort_array(array, score);
```

without for loops as there are for loops already in the sort_array function which will sort the complete array once you pass the base address of the array.

And, make sure you're calling sort_array from input_score or main function.